# Using UpscaleDB transactions in read-only file system

Tags: .net, database

### Background

I've got an application written using C# and [UpscaleDB](https://upscaledb.com/). It works as expected, however recently I made a decision to make the network drive where I store the DB files read only.

For my application this should be irrelevant, as it only reads data from the UpscaleDB files.
However, I started getting `failed with OS status 5 (Access is denied.)` exceptions.

### My code

I open the `*.hdb` file using the following code:

```cs
var env = new Upscaledb.Environment();
var file = IO.Path.Combine(path, "data.hdb");
if (IO.File.Exists(file))
{
  let flags = Upscaledb.UpsConst.UPS_ENABLE_TRANSACTIONS;
  env.Open(file, flags);
}
```

I worked out that adding a flag `Upscaledb.UpsConst.UPS_READ_ONLY` helps here, but then I get an exception when attempting to use the transaction system (this part of code actually uses F#):

```ml
use txn = this.Env.Begin()
let rslt = f(txn)
txn.Commit() // <-- throws "failed with OS status 5 (Access is denied.)"
```

According to the documentation, there's a flag [`Upscaledb.UpsConst.UPS_TXN_READ_ONLY`](http://files.upscaledb.com/documentation/html/group__ups__txn.html) for read-only transactions, but using it brings no change.

Also, I noticed that any read operation provided as the `f` parameter executes just fine. While debugging, I can see the right data being read from the DB file.

### Question

Is there a way to use UpscaleDB with transactions in a read-only file system? Or maybe the only way for me is to rewrite my system in order to remove transactions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://files.upscaledb.com/documentation/html/group__ups__env.html#ga3f347d5c9b11301c45c3f27624b5f55a), enabling transactions automatically enables journaling as well.

I found out that disabling it (by setting the `UPS_DISABLE_RECOVERY` flag) sorts out my problem. In my case I'm happy to accept the tradeoff.